# "Upgrade Metadata" prompt in ArcCatalog

Tags: arccatalog, metadata

A few months we began seeing a pop up in ArcCatalog when hitting the "Description" tab asking if you want to upgrade metadata. Clicking yes or no results in the existing metadata being deleted. Clicking the x to close the pop up is the only way to keep the existing metadata intact. Is this a known bug or am I missing something? Searched around with Google but didn't find much.
[image: Upgrade Metadata prompt in ArcCatalog]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable this upgrade prompt in ArcCatalog Options (**Customize > ArcCatalog Options > Metadata tab**).

ESRI has completely changed the format of metadata with ArcGIS 10+ and haven't done a very good job of it at all. It's causing a lot of issues for those of us who actually make use of metadata.

Have a read about what has changed:

http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2011/01/03/a-new-approach-for-metadata-with-arcgis-10/

Comment: Good to know. Does QGIS handle metadata any better?

Comment: @sirgeo Couldn't say I'm afraid. ArcGIS metadata is still good, but not if you're trying to update everything from a 9.x version.